# Why should I avoid to use _.isEqual in shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have read this question many times and everytime the suggested answer is to not use deep comparison because it is costly. I have tried to implement this in my application and it seems very fast indeed.

```
  shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    let a = +new Date();
    let equalProps = _.isEqual(this.props, nextProps);
    let equalState = _.isEqual(this.state, nextState);
    let b = +new Date();
    console.log("----> deep equality navbar took ", b - a, " result = ", equalProps && equalState);

    if (equalProps && equalState) return false;

    return true;
  };
```

And here is a sample of log produced:

```
----> deep equality msg list took  0  result =  false
----> deep equality msg list took  0  result =  false
----> deep equality navbar took  0  result =  true
----> deep equality sidebar took  0  result =  true
----> deep equality msg list took  1  result =  false
```

Basically, it seems to never go over the 1 millisecond, and I am dealing with some 6/7 levels nested objects. The render of the message list takes over 70ms normally.. I can avoid easily with a function call that takes less than 1ms.

I am missing something big here? It seems almost to be good to be true.. roast me :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using small sample data so you did not find any speed issue, if there is big data to compare then it will big issue because `componentshouldupdate` run on every state Update so if `lodash.isEqual` takes some time it will slow down react page render speed

you can see below a list of object compare and find batter one you project

```
fast-deep-equal x 226,960 ops/sec ±1.55% (86 runs sampled)
nano-equal x 218,210 ops/sec ±0.79% (89 runs sampled)
shallow-equal-fuzzy x 206,762 ops/sec ±0.84% (88 runs sampled)
underscore.isEqual x 128,668 ops/sec ±0.75% (91 runs sampled)
lodash.isEqual x 44,895 ops/sec ±0.67% (85 runs sampled)
deep-equal x 51,616 ops/sec ±0.96% (90 runs sampled)
deep-eql x 28,218 ops/sec ±0.42% (85 runs sampled)
assert.deepStrictEqual x 1,777 ops/sec ±1.05% (86 runs sampled)
ramda.equals x 13,466 ops/sec ±0.82% (86 runs sampled)
The fastest is fast-deep-equal
```

https://github.com/epoberezkin/fast-deep-equal

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am not using small sample data. I am using production data from a webmail project. Message list actually contains 50 full email messages and lot of other stuff..., sidebar receive as props ~1000 folders, labels etc... and each of these entities are pretty nested and complex objects

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but that's still something I'd consider a fairly small sample size. I've worked on a react/redux app that handles millions of messages every minute and even that doesn't match what some apps require.

Comment: @GMchris I'm curious about the performance in this case, is it still ok if you use isEqual? For example, compare previous state with current state?

Comment: @SangĐặng You need to be a bit selective with it, I'd say. I've made this wrapper using `recompose`'s `shouldUpdate` method.

`
const propsEqual = props => shouldUpdate((curr, next) => {
  if (!props) return !_.isEqual(curr, next);

  for (let i = 0, prop; i < props.length; i += 1) {
    prop = props[i];
    if (!_.isEqual(curr[prop], next[prop])) return true;
  }

  return false;
});
`
Where `props` is an array of strings saying which properties to look at. I usually only monitor `ids` and things that are likely to change, and avoid objects and arrays. ` Excuse the formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing a large data set to itself over and over on `state` or `prop` change, you could simply utilize and compare against a date object to let the component know if it needs to be rerendered. For example, a `retrieved` date object could be updated if the `messages` data changes; now, instead of a large data compare, it can be compared against itself:

```
class MessageList extends Component {
  state = {
    retrieved: {},
    messages: [],
    err: ''
  }

  fetchMessages = () => {
    this.props.fetchMessages()
    .then(({data}) => this.setState({ messages: data, retrieved: new Date() }))
    .catch(err => this.setState({ err: err.toString() })) 

  shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => (
    nextState.retrieved > this.state.retrieved || nextState.err !== this.state.err 
  ) // this would compare a retrieved date and/or an err; it will only rerender if either has changed

  render = () => ( ... )

 }
```

This will remain **consistent** across browsers and different devices, even if your application scales up to include more data, more props, and more state.

Comment: mm I am afraid you did not understand my question. Server does not do anything here... it is happening everything on the client.. you totally misunderstood my question sorry

Comment: Even if everything is happening client-side, you shouldn't need to compare a large data set to itself is nothing has changed. Use a simple flag.